# Get Length of nested JavaScript object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I want to fill a list with elements from a database. The data comes from a PHP file in JSON format. The JSON looks like this:

```json
{"Venues" : [{"name":"McManus Galleries","id":"1"},{"name":"Dundee Law","id":"2"},{"name":"University of Abertay","id":"3"},{"name":"Baxter Park","id":"4"},{"name":"Overgate Shopping Centre","id":"5"}]}
```

Now I am handling this text with the following code:

```js
obj = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

document.getElementById("list").innerHTML = "<a onclick='getVenue("+obj.Venues[0].id + ")'>" + obj.Venues[0].name + "</a><br>";
document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += "<a onclick='getVenue("+obj.Venues[1].id + ")'>" + obj.Venues[1].name + "</a><br>";
```

...and it works, but now I want to do it with a `for-loop` so no matter how many items "Venues" contains it is showing them all in the list. I got this code right now:

```js
for(i = 0; i < obj.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += obj.Venues[i].name;
}
```

The problem here is, that `obj.length` returns 1. Does anybody know how to solve this?

Comment: `obj.Venues.length`.

Comment: You're iterating `obj.Venues`, not `obj`.

Comment: Worked, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`obj` is the main object that has child `Venues` (that is an array to be used for iteration as below)

```js
for(i = 0; i < obj.Venues.length; i++){
  document.getElementById("list").innerHTML += obj.Venues[i].name;
}
```

Comment: For some reasons it was not possible to accept the answer so early